# Unbounded Solutions of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I'm trying to get the $n$ value that makes all solutions of the ODE below $$y''+ ny = \cos(nx)$$ to be unbounded.
I found that the only value of $n$ which can make all answers unbounded is *zero*.
But, the test where the question is are saying $0$ or $1$.
I just wanna know where I'm missing something.

For $n > 0$, that includes $n=1$, the answer is $Y(x) = A.\cos(\sqrt{n}x)+B.\sin(\sqrt{n}x)+Y_p(x)$. In my understanding $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions are not unbounded, right?

Also, for $n < 0$ the answer is $Y(x) = A.e^{\sqrt{n}x}+B.e^{-\sqrt{n}x}+Y_p(x)$, which have the second term limited, right?

So, for $n=0$ the answer is $Y(x) = Bx + \frac{x^2}{2}+A$, that in my vision are unbounded.

So, why 1 gives an answer where all solutions are unbounded?

Comment: Thanks @runway44 and sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 3):

**(1) When $n >0$**, $$y''+ny=0 \implies y_g=C_1 \sin(x\sqrt{n})+ C_2 \cos(x\sqrt{n})$$
and $$ (D^2+n)y_p=\cos nx \implies y_p= \frac{\cos nx}{D^2+n} \implies y_p=\frac{\cos nx}{-n^2+n}$$
So the total solution is $$y(x)=C_1 \sin(x\sqrt{n})+ C_2 \cos(x\sqrt{n})+\frac{\cos nx}{n-n^2}$$

**(2)When $n=1$**,  $$y''-y=\cos x \implies y_g(x)=C_1 e^x+C_2 e^{-x}, y_p(x)=\frac{\cos x}{D^2-1}=\frac{\cos x}{-1-1}=-\frac{1}{2} \cos x$$
 $$y(x)=C_1 e^{x} + C_2 e^{-x}-\frac{1}{2} \cos x$$

**(3)When $n<0, n=-m, m>0$**,$$ y''-my=\cos mx \implies y_g(x)= C_1 e^{\sqrt{m}x}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{m}x}, y_p=\frac{\cos mx}{D^2-m}=\frac{\cos mx}{-m^2-m}=-\frac{1}{m^2+m} \cos x$$ then $$y(x)=C_1 e^{\sqrt{m}x}+ C_2 e^{-\sqrt{m}x}-\frac{1}{m^2+m} \cos x.$$

**(4)When $n=0$**, $$y''=1 \implies y'=x+A \implies y=x^2/2+Ax+B$$

Comment: so, thanks for answering, but, why is the all solutions unbounded of $y=C_1 \sin x +C_2 \cos x+\frac{1}{2} x \sin x$? $cosx$ and $sinx$ are not unbound right?

Comment: @FELINTONETO They aren't, but $x\sin(x)/2$ is, and adding a bounded function to it doesn't change that.

Comment: @FELINTO NETO I have solved the ODE completely  whatever comes has to accepted, In fact $y_g$ is bounded but $y_p=x\sin(x)/2$ is unbounded which can go to $\pm \infty$. Choose whicever you want.

Comment: Thanks @DrZafarAhmedDSc but my ask is, all solutions unbounded, note the general solution. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @FELINTO NETO Please see my edited answer.